# Python input arguments and input stdin data

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, stdin

I want to write a python script that requires one argument as input, followed by the data as stdin. So at the end I want to be able to run the program as follows:

```
cat mydata | ./mycode.py -inx 2:5 -
```

or without dash:

```
cat mydata | ./mycode.py -inx 2:5
```

The input argument specifies which columns should be considered in the code.

I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Perhaps you want [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sys.stdin gives you a stream object from standard input. You can then just use it as a stream.